# Why does my minecraft sprint stop when hitting an entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For some reason, my sprint instantly stops when I hit a player or entity. This makes PVP harder for me. I've tried looking this up and have found no solution. My sprint key is usually DELETE but someone said if you use L-Control it fixes it but sadly it didn't for me.

Comment: Just hold the sprint key.

Comment: Fabian's comment is what I use.  I actually bind sprint to the Q key which makes it very easy to hold the button while sprinting forward.  You would have to bind drop item to a different key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal game operation.  A quote from the [wiki on sprinting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sprinting):

> Sprinting ends when the player collides with a solid block, sneaks, blocks or attacks a mob.